# Why is a 'Markov Random Field' a field?

Tags: markov-process

In particular, I'm not seeing how a commutative group is defined on a graph, nor addition and multiplication.

So why is it a [field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_%28mathematics%29#Definition_and_illustration)?

Comment: ...and why doesn't it have a [crop or pasture growing in it](https://www.google.com/search?q=field+definition), either?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think anyone ever intended it to be a field in the sense in which that term is used in algebra.  The word "field" is one of those words that have many different meanings, varying with the context. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field

Fields, in the sense used in algebra are used in statistics in the combinatorial problems arising in the design of experiments.  Quite a different thing from this.